# Using the Ansible find module to search based on permissions

Tags: ansible, find

How could this be done in Ansible?

```sh
find . -name "*.sh" -type f  ! -perm 754
```

So, using the Ansible find module to search based on permissions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot bake this into the `find` module itself.

But you can get all the files matching your pattern and then, filter the result based on the rights you want.

So, this will be a two tasks solution:

```yaml
- find:
    paths: /usr/local/ansible
    patterns: '*.sh'
  register: find

- debug:
    var: find.files | selectattr('mode', '!=', '0754')
```

---

Given the playbook (with shell tasks for comparison):

```yaml
- hosts: localhost
  gather_facts: no

  tasks:
    - find:
        paths: /usr/local/ansible
        patterns: '*.sh'
      register: find

    - shell: find /usr/local/ansible/*.sh  -type f
      register: shell
    - name: All shell files via shell
      debug:
        var: shell.stdout
    - name: All shell files via find
      debug:
        var: find.files | map(attribute="path")

    - shell: find /usr/local/ansible/*.sh  -type f  ! -perm 754
      register: shell
    - name: All shell files having 754 perm via shell
      debug:
        var: shell.stdout
    - name: All shell files having 754 perm via find
      debug:
        var: >
          find.files
          | selectattr('mode', '!=', '0754')
          | map(attribute="path")
```

This yields:

```
TASK [shell] **************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [All shell files via shell] ******************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  shell.stdout: |-
    /usr/local/ansible/a.sh
    /usr/local/ansible/b.sh

TASK [All shell files via find] *******************************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  find.files | map(attribute="path"):
  - /usr/local/ansible/a.sh
  - /usr/local/ansible/b.sh

TASK [shell] **************************************************************
changed: [localhost]

TASK [All shell files having 754 perm via shell] **************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  shell.stdout: /usr/local/ansible/a.sh

TASK [All shell files having 754 perm via find] ***************************
ok: [localhost] => 
  find.files | selectattr('mode', '!=', '0754') | map(attribute="path"):
  - /usr/local/ansible/a.sh
```